# PingFederate Health Check Automation

Tags: pingfederate

We are planning to do an automation in PingFederate with below scenarios.

1. Ping Heart beat url check

   ```
   If URL works then fine
   If not, 
     Check Server status
     port verification
     ANYTHING NEED TO BE ADDED ?
   ```
2. Log verification to ensure all requests are getting 200 response
3. LDAP Connectivity check

Since, I'm new to pingfederate not sure on more possible verification that wee can automate as part of health check.
Can some one share the ideas & thoughts

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is in a standalone environment, not clustered? If there are other nodes in the cluster, I'd recommend doing checks between nodes for connectivity.

You could enable JMX or SMTP monitoring. These could be useful if you're experiencing an outage:

https://docs.pingidentity.com/bundle/ix_m_downloadDocumentation/page/PF904Manuals.pdf#page=152

Checking for messages at the ERROR level in the server.log file would be helpful. Usually it's indicative of a problem, or at least something worth looking at. And PingFed will complain quite loudly in the server.log if the LDAP connectivity is problematic.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to checking the Hearbeat URL, you may check for server CPU, memory and also review the [runtime properties file](https://docs.pingidentity.com/bundle/pf_sm_configurePingFederateProperties_pf83/page/concept/changingConfigurationParameters.html) for additional information checks/review. Configure your Load Balancer to poll the heartbeat URL on all the server nodes in a cluster.
Another tool for monitoring various PingFederate server resources including icmp pings, monitor heartbeat url or any application URL which is served by PingFederate, can be done with [SolarWinds monitoring](https://www.solarwinds.com/topics/website-uptime-monitoring).
Refer [this blog](https://oamoim.blogspot.com/2017/11/pingidentity-articles.html) for additional PingFederate monitoring options